# Is there a way to connect my google home mini to python so that I can send the speech to text to my python interpreter to parse

Tags: python, django, actions-on-google, speech-to-text, google-home

I want to do a side project and just wanted to know how to connect my google home mini to python code? using some api if i can send the speech the user sends to my python editor to parse through, it would do exactly what i need

Comment: Its a big and open question ... but the core of what you want will be in DialogFlow.  Through this you can build actions which accept input and can call fulfillment logic implemented as REST services which could be Python and Flask.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into [Conversational Actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/overview) which will convert the speech said by someone into their Google Home into text. It will send this text as JSON to a URL of your choice. You can have python code listening at this URL and get the value you want out of the JSON.

Comment: okay cool, so I could probably send the response to a database, and send a query to the database from python server?

Comment: It depends exactly what you mean by that, since that is a pretty broad question. There is nothing from Google that will put what the user says directly into a database - you will need to write that.

Comment: yeah that makes sense, but how do i train the google home to receive ANYTHING the user says and parse that

Comment: Did you look into the link I provided? If it doesn't answer your question, you may want to open up a new question with as much detail about your needs and what it doesn't address. You may want to give concrete examples.